# Codeigniter - accessing file in root

Tags: codeigniter

I use codeigniter framework and I have file sw.js that located in the application root folder.
I'm having trouble accessing it.
http://localhost/project/sw.js

Any help is very appreciated! Thanks

Comment: from where u r accessing that file?

Comment: just use `APPPATH.'sw.js';`

Comment: solved!..I add <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> in the begining of the .htaccess file and </IfModule> in the end...Thanks for your respond

Answer (score 0):

You must put all assets (css, images, js, plugins...) outside application folder. For example create a folder "assets" in your root path. For example usage;

```
<?=base_url('assets/js/custom.js')?>
```

And change .htaccess file like this;

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: solved!..I add <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> in the begining of the .htaccess file and </IfModule> in the end...Thanks for your respond